# How can I get a bibliography at the end of each chapter?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, natbib, overleaf

I am using this thesis template provided by my school, but they do not offer any support for it:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/colorado-school-of-mines-thesis-template/mmsgptvwxbph

Instead of having the bibliography (`thesis.bib`) generated at the end of the document, I need each chapter to have a separate bibliography generated as the last section. For example, in Chapter 2, if the last section was `2.6 Conclusions`, it would be followed by `2.7 References,` and the bibliography would be generated there.

Here is what I tried that worked for the first chapter I formatted, but not the following chapters.

I commented out `\bibliography{supporting-files/thesis}` in `mines-example-dissertation.tex`. At the end of Chapter 2, I included

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{\bibname}}
\urlstyle{rm}
\bibliography{ch2.bib}
```

This generated a bibliography at the end of Chapter 2, with a section header `2.7 References`.

Once I included chapter 3, I used the same code at the end,

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection{\bibname}}
\urlstyle{rm} 
\bibliography{ch3.bib}
```

but none of the references in Chapter 3 are citing correctly (they all look like `[? ? ?]`).

The bibliography generated at the end of Chapter 3 as a subsection is identical to the one in chapter 2, even though I used `\bibliography{ch3.bib}` it is clearly reading from the previous `ch2.bib`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. In the preamble of the template, these packages are used for references:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Creating_multiple_bibliographies_in_the_same_document ?